# Organise content by publication or by folder

Tags: 2011, blueprint

Looking to tap into the wider experience of the group here - I'm facing a choice between organising regional content (e.g. content that's only for Europe or North America) either by folder or by publication.

This is an existing implementation with a traditional diamond blueprint with a translation layer for localisations. Some regional content has already been created in the "master" publication - into named folders.

My initial instinct was to use publications to manage this regional content but this would require moving existing components and re-linking them back into pages (approx 4000 pages in total).

We could carry on creating everything in the master publication with an improved folder structure and we introduce user groups/permissions and the "*Hide organizational items if no access to content*" setting so that when editors log in they only see stuff they're allowed to - which is ultimately the same point using regional publications would get us to.

The benefit here is it cuts out having to script the moving/relinking of components.

**Does anyone have any experience of managing regional content from a single publication - is there a killer advantage to using publications over folder structure?**

**Are there any other gotchas to be aware of?**

Answer (score 2):

One reason to use separate Publications is for integration with Tridion World Server / Translation Manager.  The GUI for that in the CMS allows you to set language pairs - where each pair has a parent and child language.  This is out of the box when you install the TMS connector and have a good language Blueprint configured.

Otherwise, for security, you're correct - folders give you much of the same benefit that separate Publications do.

Comment: +1, though Technically, it'd be Translation Manager which integrates SDL Tridion with SDL WorldServer, SDL TMS, or SDL BeGlobal (the latest "cloud" translation option).

Answer (score 2):

I've seen two main questions drive whether to use folders or publications in this case.

1. Are you dealing with personalization (variations) or language translation?
2. Are authors consolidated or distributed?

### Languages or Just Variations?

**When dealing with large sets of similar content in the same language, I've seen folders work well.** Centrally managed legal disclaimers, state- or region-specific news, or anything that has a one-to-many distribution fit libraries of folders, possibly with metadata on the items to re-use them across "channels."

For this type of personalizaiton, BluePrinting *is* the gotcha and an easy counter-example if you would you add X child publications for X variations of something (e.g. 50 publications for 50 states?). I point out how [personalization differs from localization (and translation) in this post](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/localization-personalization-why-cxm-shouldnt-affect-your-sdl-tridion-blueprint-much) which was at least partially inspired by Manuel Garrido's earlier post in [Minimizing Localization](http://tridionstrategist.blogspot.com/p/sdl-tridion-blueprint-minimizing.html).

*My (personal) recommendation would be all things being equal, don't add separate publications unless you need separate publications.*

### Groups of Authors

From personal experience and because the folders are often identical, **multiple publications can be tedious for a central authoring group**. Have you ever created content in the wrong publication?

However, I've seen a few setups where **multiple publications work well with a central IT team supporting several distributed (possibly internal) organizations**. Examples of this *pseudo* multi-tenant setup include:

- **Mini-sites**: start and manage a quick new site independent of other branches in the BluePrint
- **Campuses with many departments or organizations**: authorization is simplified to scope with a relatively flat BluePrint

Folders versus publications don't seem to matter as much for companies with few translation requirements, which is the biggest gotcha. Two *regional* publications implies two sets of translation publications in the translation layer. Otherwise you may need multiple content sources [like this](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-CEDF4C19-E3C9-4CA3-8D7B-FF206B98CCEA) (login required), which I'm still trying to confirm if this works in practice.